# Why given 2 arguments, TypeError: takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)?

Tags: dynamic, dynamic-programming, fibonacci, indexoutofrangeexception

I do not know why my function that takes two arguments, when given two arguments, returns an error that says I have only have given one argument. I am trying to get the output of a fibonacci algorithm then multiply that by the second user input.

Thanks

```
 29 def population(n,k):
 30     n = int(sys.argv[1])
 31     k = int(sys.argv[2])
 32 
 33     if n in range (1,10000):
 34         pass
 35     else:
 36         print("day out of range")
 37     if k in range(1,10000):
 38         pass
 39     else:
 40         print("growth rate out of range")
 41     FibArray = [0,1]
 42 
 43     #reproduction rate is Fn=F(n-1)+F)n-2)
 44     #start fibonacci sequence on one and end on the nth day, multiply by the rate or reproduction
 45     while len(FibArray) < n + 1:
 46         FibArray.append(0)
 47 
 48     if n <=1:
 49         return n
 50     else:
 51         if FibArray [int(n)-1]==0:
 52             FibArray[n-1]=population(n-1)
 53 
 54         if FibArray[n-2]==0:
 55             FibArray[n-2]=population(n-2)
 56 
 57     FibArray[n]= FibArray[n-2] + FibArray[n-1]
 58     X = FibArray[n]
 59     return k * X
 60 
 61 if __name__=="__main__":
 62     n = int(sys.argv[1])
 63     k = int(sys.argv[2])
 64     pop = population(n, k)
 65     print("Your population size on day {} is {}".format(n,pop))




Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fibonacci.py", line 64, in <module>
    pop = population(n, k)
  File "./fibonacci.py", line 55, in population
    FibArray[n-2]=population(n-2)
TypeError: population() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I would say that you read the error again. It says that the error is on line 55, where you have called the `population()` function with only one argument that is `(n-2)`. That is creating a problem. You need to rectify your code there.

Comment: Do you think adding a k to that part of the function will solve it? -->  FibArray[n-2]=population(n-2,k)